# Cannot access field in Django Graphene

Tags: django, graphql, field, graphene-python

The field which is specified in my models file is not included in the GraphiQL, I have tried to rename the field, delete it and define it again, even changing the type of field also updating the graphene-django package. None of these I have mentioned didn't work. The name of the field I can't get is named **book**

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

from books.models import Book


class Borrowing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    returned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_borrowed = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    date_returned = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} borrowed {self.book.title}'
```

schema.py

```
import graphene
from .mutations.borrowings import *
from backend.functions import pagination

PAGE_SIZE = 12

class BorrowingMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    borrow_book = BorrowBook.Field()
    return_book = ReturnBook.Field()


class BorrowingQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    borrowings = graphene.List(BorrowingType)
    users_borrowings = graphene.List(BorrowingType, page=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_borrowings(self, info):
        return Borrowing.objects.all()

    def resolve_users_borrowings(self, info, page):
        user = info.context.user
        borrowings = Borrowing.objects.filter(user=user, returned=False)
        borrowings = pagination(PAGE_SIZE, page, borrowings)

        return borrowings
```

Type

```
class BorrowingType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Borrowing
```

Comment: To debug try adding a custom resolver with some print statements ( `resolve_book`) to see first of all of the custom resolver is even being called. If it the resolver isn't called, next try adding the field book explicitly to the `BorrowingType` class.

Comment: I would also go with the @MarkChackerian 's solution. I was going to post the same resolution when I read the question. CrazyCatCZ you should try the solution